# How can I create an installable OS X Leopard DVD from a running system?

Tags: macos, leopard

I need to reinstall Leopard on a computer although I don't have the install disks. Leopard is still installed on the computer. Also the disk drive doesn't work. What options are there? Can I create a bootable USB somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create an installation disc from an installed Leopard system.

You can contact Apple for replacement installation discs. If I remember correctly they charge an amount for the service and shipping, at which point you might want to consider buying a more recent version of the OS instead.